# How can I have 'guardRoute' run before 'mapUnknownRoutes' in Durandaljs Router?

Tags: durandal, durandal-navigation

I'm using the [Router](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api.html#module/router) in [Durandaljs](http://durandaljs.com/) to control routing in a SPA. In my application all routes are created dynamically.  Therefore I use only [mapUnknownRoutes](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api.html#class/Router/method/mapUnknownRoutes) for mapping all routes.  The problem I have is that if the user navigates between different hashes in the same page, clicking on 'back' leads to unloading the current page - something I wish to prevent.  I thought of doing this by using [guardRoute](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api.html#class/Router/method/guardRoute) and there return 'false' when navigation remains in the same page, but 'guardRoute' runs only after 'mapUnknownRoutes' hence does not prevent the unloading of the current page.

Any suggestions?

Thanks !

Elior